# How to detect a mouse_down on a Userform Frame while the mouse is still down

Tags: excel, vba, userform, mousedown

I want to detect when there's a mouse_down on any Frame on the Form while the mouse is still down.  I know how to do it for a Click, but I want to catch it before mouse_up.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the mouse_down event do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `_MouseDown` event handler for each frame on the form, or if you have many frames you can create a generic event handler class

Create a Class module (eg named `cUserFormEvents`)

```
Public WithEvents Frme As MSForms.frame
Public frm As UserForm

Private Sub Frme_MouseDown( _
 ByVal Button As Integer, _
 ByVal Shift As Integer, _
 ByVal X As Single, _
 ByVal Y As Single)

    ' Put your event code here
    MsgBox Frme.Caption

End Sub
```

Declare a collection for your Frames

```
Dim mcolFrames As New Collection
```

Include this code in your form initialistion

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
    Dim clsEvents As cUserFormEvents

    'Loop through all controls on userform
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        'Only process Frames
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.frame Then
            'Instantiate class module and assign properties
            Set clsEvents = New cUserFormEvents
            Set clsEvents.Frme = ctl
            Set clsEvents.frm = Me

            'Add instance to collection
            mcolFrames.Add clsEvents

        End If

    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Now, `Frme_MouseDown` will execute on MouseDown on any Frame on the form.  Access the specific Frame with `Frme`

Comment: a belated +1 for this.  I've used it now in several different forms and it works great.

Comment: +1 I used the same approach to create a mouseEventListener for mousedown on a PowerPoint userform instead of on each frame inside the form. Worked perfectly.