# how to detect Frame_Enter events from a class module

Tags: excel, mouseenter, userform, vba

This is a follow-on question to the one answered here:
[How to detect a mouse_down on a Userform Frame while the mouse is still down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466376/how-to-detect-a-mouse-down-on-a-userform-frame-while-the-mouse-is-still-down)

Using code from the answer to that question, I can successfully detect MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseMove on any frame on the form.  However, there's apparently no Frame_Enter or Frame_Exit events available in the cls.  Is there a way to simulate a Frame_Enter event in the class module?

Edit:
Here's what I'm trying to do.  I have 8 frames loaded with 8 pictures that, when combined in a larger frame make up a larger picture.  Think of a jigsaw with 8 rectangular pieces.  Normally, all 8 frames hold a "dimmed" (neutral filter overlay) version of their picture, but when the mouse enters any of them it triggers the loading of an "undimmed" version of the picture in the newly entered frame, and a dimmed version of the picture in the just exited frame.  So if the mouse is over any of these frames, it's always moving over a bright picture that is surrounded by dimmed pictures.

As the mouse moves around an undimmed frame, it rolls over an unlimited number of "hotspot" triggers that cause a textbox to pop up with more info about what the mouse is currently hovering over.  When it leaves that frame and moves over another, the process repeats.

Everything is working except for detecting when the mouse moves across a frame boundary and into the next frame.  This has to be detected before any MouseMove events can be handled.

Here's a method that looks promising, if nothing else is suggested:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showpost.php?p=2567141&postcount=28

Edit2:  It still looks promising but I can't make it work.  It doesn't seem to issue the enter and exit events until after I click on the control, which is of no use to me.

So chris, back to yours.  You're watching the Frame_MouseMove events and waiting for a different Frame to issue the event than last time.  I'm wondering if instead of using your auxiliary textBox to signal the change, could you not use a static variable to keep track of currentFrame/prevFrame?

Comment: That's what my code does. :) So instead of using `Frame1_MouseMove` and `UserForm_MouseMove`, you can use only `_MouseMove` of frames to store the values in variables?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but there is no direct way you can trap the `_Enter` and `_Exit` event of a frame. However there is an alternative

```
Option Explicit

Dim temp As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    temp = "OnForm"
End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If temp = "OnForm" Then
        Debug.Print "The mouse just entered the frame"
        temp = "OnFrame"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If temp = "OnFrame" Then
        Debug.Print "The mouse just exited the frame"
        temp = "OnForm"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There's already a Frame_Enter event which works fine if you know which Frame to look at.  But there's no Frame_Enter event available from a class module when using the method in the Answer that I referenced.  Your method wouldn't work for my purposes because I need to do stuff before the MouseMove event is issued, and that's what Frame_Enter would do for me, if there was such a thing.

Comment: If I am not wrong then Frame_Enter event fires the moment the userform is loaded. It has nothing to do with mouse entering the frame? if you can explain, what exactly you are trying to do then maybe I can suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

Key word: *Simulate*

Using a combination of Frame `Mouse_Move` and Form `Mouse_Move`

Demonstration using a Text Boxes called `txtWhereAmI` (initialise Value proiperty to `Form`)
`txtEntry` `txtExit` (initialise Value proiperties to `0`)

In Class module declare Frame MouseMove

```
Private Sub Frme_MouseMove( _
 ByVal Button As Integer, _
 ByVal Shift As Integer, _
 ByVal X As Single, _
 ByVal Y As Single)

    UserForm1.txtWhereAmI.Value = Frme.Caption
End Sub
```

In Form module declare Form Mouse Move

```
Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove( _
  ByVal Button As Integer, _
  ByVal Shift As Integer, _
  ByVal X As Single, _
  ByVal Y As Single)
    txtWhereAmI.Value = "Form"
End Sub
```

and Text Box Change event

```
Private Sub txtWhereAmI_Change()
    If txtWhereAmI.Value = "Form" Then
        txtExit = txtExit + 1
    Else
        txtEntry = txtEntry + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Result: `txtWhereAmI` identifies which frame the mouse is over, `txtEntry` and `txtExit` count entry and exit events

The `Change` event of `txtWhereAmI` then forms the basis of your `Entry` and `Exit` event handler

Comment: chris, I don't think that would work for me because all the Frames that I want to work with are touching, and in fact have a one pixel overlap,  so the mouse doesn't go from frame to form to frame, but rather it goes directly from frame to frame.  I'll describe what I'm trying to do by editing my original post.  These comment boxes are pretty awful.

Comment: Event so, the idea still works, `txtWhereAmI_Change` event still fires, with the value changing from one frame name to the next.  Comes down to what you want to do with the Entry and Exit events and writting the Change event code to suit.