# Detect mouse down event on dynamic objects in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform, mousedown

I have a dynamic range of OptionButtons within a frame in a Userform. The number of OptionButtons  vary according to number of columns in a table. Each button is labeled according the column label. When a person selects an option I need a ListBox to be populated with the items found within that table column. 
Populating the option buttons and ListBox is easy enough. I know how to detect mouse down events on known Userformobjects. But the buttons exist only through coding and vary. How do I detect MouseDown on an object that doesn't actually exist?
I have tried the code for creating a MouseDown Class for a Frame

Comment: Creating a class to handle events on runtime created objects is the correct approach,  but you say you've tried that.   Show us that code

Comment: I clearly remember writing an answer a while back about handling events for dynamic controls, but I could't find it :(

Comment: I used the code from this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466376/how-to-detect-a-mouse-down-on-a-userform-frame-while-the-mouse-is-still-down?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your controls in a class module - say, `DynamicOptionButton`:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents ControlEvents As MSForms.OptionButton

Public Sub Initialize(ByVal ctrl As MSForms.OptionButton)
    If Not ControlEvents Is Nothing Then ThrowAlreadyInitialized
    Set ControlEvents = ctrl
End Property

Private Property Get AsControl() As MSForms.Control
    Set AsControl = ControlEvents
End Property

Private Sub ThrowAlreadyInitialized()
    Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Invalid Operation: This control is already initialized."
End Sub

Private Sub ControlEvents_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Dim parentForm As UserForm1 'todo: use your actual UserForm subtype
    Set parentForm = AsControl.Parent 
    'handle mousedown here.
End Sub
```

When you create the dynamic controls, you'll want a **module-level** `Collection` to hold the `DynamicOptionButton` instances - otherwise they'll **go out of scope** when `End Sub` is reached, and you'll never be able to handle any of their events.

```
Private DynamicControls As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set DynamicControls = New Collection
    'todo invoke CreateOptionButton
End Sub

Private Sub CreateOptionButton() 'todo parameterize
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.OptionButton
    Set ctrl = Me.Controls.Add(...)

    Dim wrapper As DynamicOptionButton
    Set wrapper = New DynamicOptionButton
    wrapper.Initialize ctrl

    DynamicControls.Add wrapper
End Sub
```

Comment: What was missing from your code description was that the label of ControlEvents was to be used to identify the objects such as ControlEvents.Caption and ControlEvents.Value. Before working that out, though the code was working, it wasn't telling me which OptionButton was being selected. But now it is all good and works fantastically. Thanks a bunch

Comment: You can also cast it to `MSForms.Control` and use the `Tag` property to hold metadata like an ID - that way the logic isn't dependent on a caption, which in other scenarios might need to be localized: avoiding to use UI-only stuff (like a caption) like metadata (e.g. a unique ID) helps separate concerns and makes things more robust as a whole. Cheers!